# Magento 2: FedEx shipping method throwing error on frontend

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, fedex

I have setup FedEx shipping method using test development credentials in Magento 2. I obtained these credentials by signing up for web services on fedex.com. After entering these details from the Magento 2 admin panel, still on the checkout page, an error message is displayed below the shipping method as -

**"This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."**

Please see the error screenshot -

[image: here]

I am using Magento 2.01 version. What might be the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck on this since a couple of days :)

Comment: check var/logs or var/reports and see if any errors are there regarding this.

Comment: in exception.log it says - main.CRITICAL: SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in \Magento_CE\vendor\magento\module-fedex\Model\Carrier.php:491.. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the web services url was blocked in my office. I went home and carried out the process from different network and Voila ! It worked smoothly.

Comment: How can i solve by same error in mage ver 1.9.2.3

Comment: @Aveeva : Have you tried the same from a different network?

Comment: could u pls help me how can i configure fedex display rate based in weight.

Comment: @Aveeva : can u be more elaborative pls and describe your exact error. I'll be glad to help :)

Comment: @ piyush : how can i configure fedex shipping like if user select shipping method fedex, its display shipping cost based on products weight and customer location (Actually  shipping cost calculated by weight an distance) , i am new for magento, how can i configure shipping method for my usa site

Comment: @Aveeva : As far as my knowledge goes, the shipping costs are calculated by parameters set by Fedex corp. These values are obtained by us using the API. For further customisation/enhancement to shipping rates, I think contacting the Fedex support would help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56906/discussion-between-aveeva-and-piyush-dangre).